# incompatible pointer types sending "NSString" to parameter of type 'AVAudioSessionPortDescription*

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avaudiosession

Trying to use only builtIn iPhone MIC for my app.

```
- (BOOL)setPreferredInput:(AVAudioSessionPortDescription *)inPort error:(NSError **)outError NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
{
 NSError* audioError = nil;
AVAudioSession* myAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[myAudioSession setPreferredInput:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic error:&audioError];
```

Comment: It looks like you may have left out a closing brace `}` somewhere. Also, the type of `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic` is `NSString *` according to Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionPortDescription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Input_Port_Types. I think the solution is to scan the array of available ports and find the one with the `type` property equal to `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic`.

Answer (score 1):

`AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic` is an `NSString`, not an `AVAudioSessionPortDescription`. In order to get the descriptors for the available ports on the device, use `[AVAudioSession availableInputs]`.

```
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *input in [AVAudioSession availableInputs]) {
  if ([[input portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [AVAudioSession setPreferredInput:input error:&error];
  }
}
```

Comment: `@property (readonly) NSArray * availableInputs NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *input in [AVAudioSession availableInputs]) {
    if ([[input portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [AVAudioSession setPreferredInput:input error:&error];
    }
}` getting unexpected "@" in program and Expected identifier error.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you have `@property (readonly)...` in your method, but it appears that you may be lacking a fundamental understanding of Objective-C programming.

Comment: I am new to Obj C programming. I am trying to override audio input to built-in mic, can you tell me how to implement this?